# How can I recover settings, extensions, and other VS Code user configuration that I accidentally lost?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was playing around with my VSCode Settings Sync, and accidentally replaced my `settings.json` file with another one from a fresh install, as a consequence, I lost my entire `settings.json` configuration.

Is there a way to recover the lost settings.json file?

I checked my backups, however, it seems that I one cannot go back into the `/Users/mf/Library/Application Support/Code/User/Sync` folder.

Comment: why do you think VSC would create a backup of all it does, VSC assumes that you know what you do, if you do something new make a backup yourself, if these where stored on an SSD you might get them back with a file recovery tool

Comment: I just lost EVERYTHING on my settings because I turned sync on. I can't find any backups anywhere. It's just frustrating, really. I'm almost turning the vscode folder into a git repo and versioning the settings file myself

Answer (score 6):

## Yes you can get them back.

#### They are saved on the hard-drive if your settings are set to their default values.

---

###### The universal method (works the same for all systems) is to hit the [F1] key, then type the command below into the input, until you see the option. When you do see the option click on it to open the directory.

#### `Settings Sync: Open Backups Folder`

###### The other option you have is to view the data in VSCode using the following VSCode command from your quick input using the [F1] key followed by the same instructions for the command above.

#### `Settings Sync: Show Synced Data`

---

There should be several saved versions of your settings, unless you have changed your configuration for *settings sync* in the settings menu, or in your user/workspace `settings.json` file.

Personally I like to just open backup folders and pullout what I need. If you are like me, and you use **Ubuntu** then the path below is the path used by VSCode to store backed-up keybindings & Settings.json instances. You can pullout what ever you need from that directory.

```
~/.config/Code/User/settings.json
```

---

If you need to restore the backed up files, you can visit this link, it demonstrates how to return to a previous editor configuration:

###### RESTORE PREVIOUS VS CODE CONFIGURATION:

- ###### *https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync#_restoring-data*

---

Comment: unfortunately the "Backups Folder" only contains extensions from yesterday, after the sync was done, i.e. not settings/folders from BEFORE the sync.

Comment: Ah. I see. I actually have data from there, before the sync erase happened. But the format is weird. How do I restore this backup?

Comment: @FooBar This is the link that explains restoring your saved editor configuration to a previous point: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync#_restoring-data

Comment: i restore my settings from "Settings Sync: Show Synced Data", thanks!